# Is there a way to use aws s3 as file system inside docker?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying to deploy an elastic beanstalk flask app on AWS using docker, the flask app will save user image, CSV files inside the container, but when I docker run the app shows an error, thinking that the image or CSV is not saved, and trying to upload the files to aws s3, what is the solution

I The script is running locally and save the output to the local system, as well as the s3 bucket
The Dockerfile is given below

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

MAINTAINER abcd@gmail.com
USER root


WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app



RUN apt-get update



RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libglib2.0-0
RUN pip install opencv-python


EXPOSE 5000
ENV NAME World

RUN ["python", "application.py"]
```

Expecting to save inside the docker and s3 bucket when I run docker